# SSL request fails during bootup because of wrong date

Tags: linux, debian, node.js

I have a boot-up script that runs a node application. When I make a request to a server, I get the following error:

```
{ [Error: certificate is not yet valid] code: 'CERT_NOT_YET_VALID' }
```

I'm assuming that the clock hasn't been synced yet, and so my computer clock is behind, and the server's clock is in the "future".

I've tried to put a dependency of `hwclock` and `$time` and even `$all` for my init script, but I still get this problem.

How can I make sure my script runs once the computer clock has synced?

Comment: Does your system boot with an approximately correct hardware clock, or does it start “blinking twelve” and need to get the time from the network? What init system do you use (sysv, bsd, upstart, systemd, …)?

Comment: @Gilles No, it does not boot with the correct time at all. It's always Dec 31, 2009 when it first boots up. So it needs to connect to network to get the new time